# Pcapdotnet: capturing wifi traffic

Tags: c#, wifi, capture, pcap.net

I'm trying to use Pcapdotnet to capture network traffic. I've been following the official tutorial up to this point

https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Interpreting-the-packets

The problem is, this tutorial only tells you how to capture ethernet traffic, "for simplicity." I'm assuming it's a question of ethernet vs wifi here? In that case, how do you capture wifi traffic and why is it less simple?
Here is the relevant line:

```
IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pcap.Net is a wrapper over WinPcap.
Quoting [WinPcap FAQ](https://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm):

> Wireless adapters: these adapters may present problems, because they
>   are not properly supported by the Windows Kernel. Some of them are not
>   detected, other don't support promiscuous mode. In the best case,
>   WinPcap is able to see an Ethernet emulation and not the real
>   transiting packets: this means that the 802.11 frames are transformed
>   into fake Ethernet frames before being captured, and that control
>   frames are not received.
>
> For real wireless capture, CACE Technologies offers the AirPcap
>   adapter, specifically designed to sniff 802.11 traffic, including
>   control frames, management frames and power information. AirPcap at
>   this time is the only solution for capturing raw 802.11 traffic with
>   WinPcap. More details can be found on the AirPcap product page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have been using it on ethernet "mode" and it's worked fine so far, even for wifi traffic, so I guess they're being transformed like you said.